# Does READ UNCOMMITTED make any performance difference on static data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, performance, performance-tuning, query-performance

I have some static tables that gets a lot of select queries

I wonder if i add this to each query, does that make any performance difference?

SQL server 2014

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

here my wait times after i have executed the below query

```
    select * 
from sys.dm_os_wait_stats
WHERE [wait_type] NOT IN (
        N'CLR_SEMAPHORE',    N'LAZYWRITER_SLEEP',
        N'RESOURCE_QUEUE',   N'SQLTRACE_BUFFER_FLUSH',
        N'SLEEP_TASK',       N'SLEEP_SYSTEMTASK',
        N'WAITFOR',          N'HADR_FILESTREAM_IOMGR_IOCOMPLETION',
        N'CHECKPOINT_QUEUE', N'REQUEST_FOR_DEADLOCK_SEARCH',
        N'XE_TIMER_EVENT',   N'XE_DISPATCHER_JOIN',
        N'LOGMGR_QUEUE',     N'FT_IFTS_SCHEDULER_IDLE_WAIT',
        N'BROKER_TASK_STOP', N'CLR_MANUAL_EVENT',
        N'CLR_AUTO_EVENT',   N'DISPATCHER_QUEUE_SEMAPHORE',
        N'TRACEWRITE',       N'XE_DISPATCHER_WAIT',
        N'BROKER_TO_FLUSH',  N'BROKER_EVENTHANDLER',
        N'FT_IFTSHC_MUTEX',  N'SQLTRACE_INCREMENTAL_FLUSH_SLEEP',
        N'DIRTY_PAGE_POLL',  N'SP_SERVER_DIAGNOSTICS_SLEEP')
order by wait_time_ms desc;
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such thing as "make this query faster" [magic pixie dust](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/). To optimize performance, query tuning, indexing and more is needed.

Comment: Run `DBCC SQLPERF('sys.dm_os_wait_stats', CLEAR)` before you run the measured query (as to clean up the wait stats), then run the query and collect the stats. As posted the waits stats represent aggregated data since the server started. The presence of a large `CXPACKET` is further indication that you're missing indexes. Read carefully the article linked in my answer.

Comment: @RemusRusanu after running DBCC SQLPERF('sys.dm_os_wait_stats', CLEAR)  - all results became 0. is that expected?

Comment: @RemusRusanu i see it clears cache. now i have to wait for more query data to be collected. how can i identify CXPACKET  issue?

Answer (score 4):

If your data is immutable mark the database as read only. The query execution engine recognizes this and skips locking. However the benefits are marginal. If locking is of concern it means that a) you have locking conflicts, which implies data is not immutable or b) you acquire too many locks, which implies large scans which needs to be addressed by adding an index as needed.

For more details read [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/).

Comment: remus data is static why? because only updated manually in offline mode. and there are proper indexes. so under these circumstances, does READ UNCOMMITTED make any difference?

Answer (score 1):

`READ UNCOMMITTED` is the same as using `NOLOCK`, and if the data isn't changing, it will provide the same performance benefits as `NOLOCK`.

This is **NOT** a go-faster button for everything, though. Uncommitted data is uncommitted data, and should not be trusted if the underlying data does change often. Make very sure you use it in the right context.

I'd also look at covering indexes, meaning indexes that satisfy your queries. You may also find joy with filtered indexes. I'd sooner look there before turning on `NOLOCK` / `READ UNCOMMITTED`.

Comment: i already have the indexes. assume that these are static and updated only offline manually. so lets say nolock or READ UNCOMMITTED, would any of them make performance difference under these circumstances?

Comment: Certainly it would make a difference, but I couldn't tell you what those differences are. They might be microseconds of improvement, or milliseconds. You'll have to do some testing to find out. Use `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` to compare.